# Objective C : constant strings and c strings

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring

In Objective-C, I sometimes forget the `@` that defines constant strings. See this example :

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      @"Red", @"Green", "Blue", @"Yellow", nil];
```

In the example, I forgot the `@` in front of the "Blue" string. This leads to annoying "Bad Access" bugs.

How to prevent these issues ? Is there some way with XCode to detect these strings or to display warnings ?

Comment: Proper testing prevents this from making it to release. Beyond that, you're on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the literal syntax considers that an error

```
NSArray *colors = @[@"Red", @"Green", "Blue", @"Yellow"];
```

Like seen below

[image]

Comment: It gives an error because it uses `arrayWithObjects:count:` which expects `const id[]` as the first parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Run the analyzer, it'll show this:

> Argument to 'NSArray' method 'arrayWithObjects:' should be an Objective-C pointer type, not 'char *'